# What bzr version did I branch from?

Tags: bazaar

I did a "bzr branch" from my team's bazaar repository and then committed some changes to my local branch. How can I determine what revision number I initially branched from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run `bzr missing URL/to/team/branch` and see what's the lowest number of your and theirs revisions (in the case branches have diverged). Previous number is the point where from you branched.

Comment: This does it, except when the upstream revision numbers change, which led me to ask this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5129660/find-the-bzr-revno-corresponding-to-a-revision-id

Answer (score 0):

Look at `bzr log` the revision after your commits is the one you branched from. The branch point is not stored by Bazaar as far as I know.

Comment: How can I tell from the bzr log? It's possible that I happened to be the last person to commit before branching.

Comment: In that case its not possible unless you have access to the original branch, then you can run `bzr missing [OTHER_BRANCH]`. Using the option `--mine-only` will show you a list of what you added locally.

Answer (score 0):

If your team's branch is named differently to your local branch, you can run `bzr log` and look at the `branch nick:` field. The first revision with your team's branch name is the base revision.

Alternatively, you could look at the creation date of your branch folder. Check that against the timestamps in the commit log.